# CSS Positioning: Fixed and relative interchangeable regarding absolute?

Tags: css

With regards to `absolute` positioning, `fixed` seems to work like `relative`.

```css
.fixed, .relative {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.fixed {
  border-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}

.relative {
  border-color: blue;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
}

.a {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.b {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <span class="absolute a">Left Top</span>
  <span class="absolute b">Right Bottom</span>
</div>

<div class="relative">
  <span class="absolute a">Left Top</span>
  <span class="absolute b">Right Bottom</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand why. I expect this to be defined somewhere, but I was only able to find resources discussing `absolute` and `relative`, not `absolute` and `fixed`.

This leads the to the question: Is it even true that, in regards to `absolute` position, I can treat `fixed` and `relative` elements the same, being able to use `top`/`left`/`right`/`bottom` to control offset amount to parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon anything other than `position:static` sets off a new parent context for the positioned children.

This can be verified in the MDN docs for **Absolute Positioning**

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static).

So  setting `position:fixed` does cause absolute child elements to follow the new context.

This can be seen it the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xfcm1xod/) . Changing the `position` of the `.rel` div moves the set of red divs , but the absolutely positioned blue div moves with it.

Another good source is the w3.org which says

> An essential concept when it comes to absolute positioning is the containing block: the block box that the position and dimensions of the absolutely positioned box are relative to. For static boxes and relatively positioned boxes the containing block is the nearest block-level ancestor—the parent element in other words. For absolutely positioned elements however it’s a little more complicated. In this case the containing block is the nearest positioned ancestor. By “positioned” I mean an element whose position property is set to relative, absolute or fixed—in other words, anything except normal static elements.

Sources :
[MDN Positon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) , [w3org absolute position](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Absolute_positioning)